# Calling convention for an unmanaged DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport, calling-convention

I created a DLL in C++ and loaded in C# with [DllImport].

1. Is __cdecl default in C++ when exporting without calling convention?
2. Is it okay to use CallingConvention.StdCall or CallingConvention.Winapi with the function __cdecl? (It worked in my test, and I don't use 'Variable Arguments')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is `__cdecl` default in C++ when exporting without calling convention?

Yes.

> Is it okay to use `CallingConvention.StdCall` or `CallingConvention.Winapi` with the function `__cdecl`?

No. Use `CallingConvention.Cdecl`. Using the wrong calling convention might appear to work for some functions, but it is wrong, and at some point you will be caught out.